# Ruby: How to write nested ifs in a concise way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-if

Is there a more concise way to write the following nested conditionals?

```
def sort_column
  if Product.column_names.include?(params[:sort])
    if params[:sort] == "price_latest" || params[:sort] == "price_average"
      "#{params[:sort]}->'#{cookies[:store_id]}'"
    else
      params[:sort]
    end
  else
    "name"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the `if-else` conditions by guard clause, altering the statement depending on the case (`if`, `unless`):

```
def sort_column
  sort = params[:sort]
  return 'name' unless Product.column_names.include?(sort)
  return "#{sort}->'#{cookies[:store_id]}'" if sort.in?(%w[price_latest price_average])

  sort
end
```

With `return name unless ...` you get rid of `if Product.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) else ... end`.

With `sort.in?(%w[price_latest price_average])` you shorten the `params[:sort] == "price_latest" || params[:sort] == "price_average"` condition and return `#{sort}->'#{cookies[:store_id]}'"` just if it returns true.

If none of the other conditions are evaluated as true, return just the value of `params[:sort]`.

Answer (score 1):

With early `return` *and* `case`.

```rb
def sort_column
  return "name" unless Product.column_names.include?(params[:sort])

  case params[:sort]
  when "price_latest", "price_average"
    "#{params[:sort]}->'#{cookies[:store_id]}'"
  else
    params[:sort]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A linear search is required to determine if `Product.column_names` contains a given element. If that array is large and will not change during execution of the code, and `sort_column` is to be called multiple times, performance can be improved by converting that array to a set. Determining whether a set contains a given element is very fast, lookup times being comparable to those for determining if a hash has a given key.

```
require 'set'
names_set = Product.column_names.to_set

def sort_column(params, names_set)
  ps = params[:sort]
  return "name" unless names_set.include?(ps)
  ["price_latest", "price_average"].include?(ps) ? 
    "#{ps}->'#{cookies[:store_id]}'" : "home"
end
```